# Why my data isn't being sent to firebase from this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the code for my feedback page. The purpose of it is to get the feedback from patients.The problem that I am facing is that the data is not being sent to firebase. I have tried using a similar code on another page and it worked perfectly but even in that at first it did not work despite deploying the website again and again and eventually it worked after i typed `console.log()`. Secondly the submit button is supposed to redirect to `index.html` but it is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>star-rating</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/feedback.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<svg style="display: none"><symbol id="star" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"><polygon points="512 0 627 354 
 999 354 698 572 813 926 512 708 211 926 326 572 25 354 397 354 512 0"/></symbol></svg>

<div id="modal">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="feedback container--small align--center">
        <a href="index.html">
            <button id="close">Close</button>
            </a>
            <h1 class="feedback__title">Patient Feedback</h1>
            <p class="feedback__description">Please let us know how our service was. It will really 
            help us to keep improving our service!</p>
            <form class="feedback_form">
            <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
            <td>
            <label>MR Number</td>  <td> <input type="text" name="mrnum" id="mrnum" placeholder="Enter 
            MR Number" required></label>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <label>Department</td>  <td> <input type="text" name="dept" id="dept" pattern="[A-Za-z] 
            {1,25}" placeholder="Enter Department" required></label>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <label>Doctor Name</td>  <td> <input type="text" name="doc" id="doc" pattern="[A-Za-z] 
            {1,25}" placeholder="Enter Doc Name" required></label>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
                <fieldset class="rating registration.attitude">
                <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                <th>Registration</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <legend>Attitude of staff</legend>
                </td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="flex-container" required>
                        <input type="radio" id="regAtt-5" name="rating__regAtt" value="5">
                        <label for="regAtt-5"><svg><title>Five Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="regAtt-4" name="rating__regAtt" value="4">
                        <label for="regAtt-4"><svg><title>Four Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="regAtt-3" name="rating__regAtt" value="3">
                        <label for="regAtt-3"><svg><title>Three Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="regAtt-2" name="rating__regAtt" value="2">
                        <label for="regAtt-2"><svg><title>Two Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="regAtt-1" name="rating__regAtt" value="1">
                        <label for="regAtt-1"><svg><title>One Star</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        </td>
                    </div>
                    </tr>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="rating registration.info">
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <legend>Information and Assistance</legend>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="flex-container" required>
                        <input type="radio" id="regInfo-5" name="rating__regInfo" value="5">
                        <label for="regInfo-5"><svg><title>Five Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="regInfo-4" name="rating__regInfo" value="4">
                        <label for="regInfo-4"><svg><title>Four Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="regInfo-3" name="rating__regInfo" value="3">
                        <label for="regInfo-3"><svg><title>Three Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="regInfo-2" name="rating__regInfo" value="2">
                        <label for="regInfo-2"><svg><title>Two Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="regInfo-1" name="rating__regInfo" value="1">
                        <label for="regInfo-1"><svg><title>One Star</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                    </use></svg></label>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>

                <fieldset class="rating registration.process">
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <legend>Registration process</legend>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="flex-container" required>
                        <input type="radio" id="regreg-5" name="rating__regreg" value="5">
                        <label for="regreg-5"><svg><title>Five Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="regreg-4" name="rating__regreg" value="4">
                        <label for="regreg-4"><svg><title>Four Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                       </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="regreg-3" name="rating__regreg" value="3">
                        <label for="regreg-3"><svg><title>Three Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="regreg-2" name="rating__regreg" value="2">
                        <label for="regreg-2"><svg><title>Two Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="regreg-1" name="rating__regreg" value="1">
                        <label for="regreg-1"><svg><title>One Star</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                    </use></svg></label>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>


                                <fieldset class="rating vitals.attitude">
                <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                <th>Vitals</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <legend>Attitude of staff</legend>
                </td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="flex-container" required>
                        <input type="radio" id="vitAtt-5" name="rating__vitAtt" value="5">
                        <label for="vitAtt-5"><svg><title>Five Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="vitAtt-4" name="rating__vitAtt" value="4">
                        <label for="vitAtt-4"><svg><title>Four Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="vitAtt-3" name="rating__vitAtt" value="3">
                        <label for="vitAtt-3"><svg><title>Three Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="vitAtt-2" name="rating__vitAtt" value="2">
                        <label for="vitAtt-2"><svg><title>Two Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="vitAtt-1" name="rating__vitAtt" value="1">
                        <label for="vitAtt-1"><svg><title>One Star</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                        </use></svg></label>
                        </td>
                    </div>
                    </tr>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="rating vitals.info">
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <legend>Information and Assistance</legend>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="flex-container" required>
                        <input type="radio" id="vitals_info-5" name="rating__vitals_info" value="5">
                        <label for="vitals_info-5"><svg><title>Five Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="vitals_info-4" name="rating__vitals_info" value="4">
                        <label for="vitals_info-4"><svg><title>Four Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="vitals_info-3" name="rating__vitals_info" value="3">
                        <label for="vitals_info-3"><svg><title>Three Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="vitals_info-2" name="rating__vitals_info" value="2">
                        <label for="vitals_info-2"><svg><title>Two Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="vitals_info-1" name="rating__vitals_info" value="1">
                        <label for="vitals_info-1"><svg><title>One Star</title><use 
                    xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>

                <fieldset class="rating vitals.process">
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <legend>Vitals process</legend>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="flex-container" required>
                        <input type="radio" id="vitals_process-5" name="rating__vitals_process" 
                        value="5">
                        <label for="vitals_process-5"><svg><title>Five Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="vitals_process-4" name="rating__vitals_process" 
                        value="4">
                        <label for="vitals_process-4"><svg><title>Four Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="vitals_process-3" name="rating__vitals_process" 
                        value="3">
                        <label for="vitals_process-3"><svg><title>Three Stars</title><use 
                         xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="vitals_process-2" name="rating__vitals_process" 
                        value="2">
                        <label for="vitals_process-2"><svg><title>Two Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="vitals_process-1" name="rating__vitals_process" 
                        value="1">
                        <label for="vitals_process-1"><svg><title>One Star</title><use 
                    xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>

                                <fieldset class="rating doc.waittime">
                <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                <th>Consultant/ Doctor</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <legend>Waiting Time</legend>
                </td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="flex-container" required>
                        <input type="radio" id="doc_waittime-5" name="rating__doc_waittime" 
                        value="5">
                        <label for="doc_waittime-5"><svg><title>Five Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="doc_waittime-4" name="rating__doc_waittime" 
                       value="4">
                        <label for="doc_waittime-4"><svg><title>Four Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="doc_waittime-3" name="rating__doc_waittime" 
                         value="3">
                        <label for="doc_waittime-3"><svg><title>Three Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="doc_waittime-2" name="rating__doc_waittime" 
                        value="2">
                        <label for="doc_waittime-2"><svg><title>Two Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="doc_waittime-1" name="rating__doc_waittime" 
                        value="1">
                        <label for="doc_waittime-1"><svg><title>One Star</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        </td>
                    </div>
                    </tr>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="rating doc.attitude">
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <legend>Attitude and Counselling</legend>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="flex-container" required>
                        <input type="radio" id="doc_attitude-5" name="rating__doc_attitude" 
                        value="5">
                        <label for="doc_attitude-5"><svg><title>Five Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="doc_attitude-4" name="rating__doc_attitude" 
                        value="4">
                        <label for="doc_attitude-4"><svg><title>Four Stars</title><use 
                         xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="doc_attitude-3" name="rating__doc_attitude" 
                        value="3">
                        <label for="doc_attitude-3"><svg><title>Three Stars</title><use 
                         xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="doc_attitude-2" name="rating__doc_attitude" 
                        value="2">
                        <label for="doc_attitude-2"><svg><title>Two Stars</title><use 
                         xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="doc_attitude-1" name="rating__doc_attitude" 
                        value="1">
                        <label for="doc_attitude-1"><svg><title>One Star</title><use 
                    xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>

                <fieldset class="rating doc.rating">
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <legend>Overall Doctor Rating</legend>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="flex-container" required>
                        <input type="radio" id="doc_rating-5" name="rating__doc_rating" value="5">
                        <label for="doc_rating-5"><svg><title>Five Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="doc_rating-4" name="rating__doc_rating" value="4">
                        <label for="doc_rating-4"><svg><title>Four Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="doc_rating-3" name="rating__doc_rating" value="3">
                        <label for="doc_rating-3"><svg><title>Three Stars</title><use 
                         xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="doc_rating-2" name="rating__doc_rating" value="2">
                        <label for="doc_rating-2"><svg><title>Two Stars</title><use 
                          xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="doc_rating-1" name="rating__doc_rating" value="1">
                        <label for="doc_rating-1"><svg><title>One Star</title><use 
                     xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>


                                <fieldset class="rating lab.waittime">
                <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                <th>Laboratory/Pharmacy</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <legend>Attitude and Guidance</legend>
                </td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="flex-container" required>
                        <input type="radio" id="lab_waittime-5" name="rating__lab_waittime" 
                        value="5">
                        <label for="lab_waittime-5"><svg><title>Five Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="lab_waittime-4" name="rating__lab_waittime" 
                        value="4">
                        <label for="lab_waittime-4"><svg><title>Four Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="lab_waittime-3" name="rating__lab_waittime" 
                        value="3">
                        <label for="lab_waittime-3"><svg><title>Three Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="lab_waittime-2" name="rating__lab_waittime" 
                        value="2">
                        <label for="lab_waittime-2"><svg><title>Two Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="lab_waittime-1" name="rating__lab_waittime" 
                        value="1">
                        <label for="lab_waittime-1"><svg><title>One Star</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        </td>
                    </div>
                    </tr>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="rating lab.delivery">
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <legend>Delivery and Availability of medicine</legend>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="flex-container" required>
                        <input type="radio" id="lab_delivery-5" name="rating__lab_delivery" 
                         value="5">
                        <label for="lab_delivery-5"><svg><title>Five Stars</title><use 
                         xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="lab_delivery-4" name="rating__lab_delivery" 
                        value="4">
                        <label for="lab_delivery-4"><svg><title>Four Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="lab_delivery-3" name="rating__lab_delivery" 
                        value="3">
                        <label for="lab_delivery-3"><svg><title>Three Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="lab_delivery-2" name="rating__lab_delivery" 
                         value="2">
                        <label for="lab_delivery-2"><svg><title>Two Stars</title><use 
                         xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="lab_delivery-1" name="rating__lab_delivery" 
                        value="1">
                        <label for="lab_delivery-1"><svg><title>One Star</title><use 
                    xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>

                    </table>

                <fieldset class="rating environment.interior">
                <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                <th>Environment</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <legend>Interior/ Directions</legend>
                </td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="flex-container" required>
                        <input type="radio" id="env_interior-5" name="rating__env_interior" 
                            value="5">
                        <label for="env_interior-5"><svg><title>Five Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="env_interior-4" name="rating__env_interior" 
                          value="4">
                        <label for="env_interior-4"><svg><title>Four Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="env_interior-3" name="rating__env_interior" 
                         value="3">
                        <label for="env_interior-3"><svg><title>Three Stars</title><use 
                         xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="env_interior-2" name="rating__env_interior" 
                         value="2">
                        <label for="env_interior-2"><svg><title>Two Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="env_interior-1" name="rating__env_interior" 
                         value="1">
                        <label for="env_interior-1"><svg><title>One Star</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        </td>
                    </div>
                    </tr>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="rating environment.temp">
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <legend>Temperature</legend>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="flex-container" required>
                        <input type="radio" id="env_temp-5" name="rating__env_temp" value="5">
                        <label for="env_temp-5"><svg><title>Five Stars</title><use 
                          xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="env_temp-4" name="rating__env_temp" value="4">
                        <label for="env_temp-4"><svg><title>Four Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="env_temp-3" name="rating__env_temp" value="3">
                        <label for="env_temp-3"><svg><title>Three Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="env_temp-2" name="rating__env_temp" value="2">
                        <label for="env_temp-2"><svg><title>Two Stars</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                         </use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="env_temp-1" name="rating__env_temp" value="1">
                        <label for="env_temp-1"><svg><title>One Star</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                    </use></svg></label>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>

                <fieldset class="rating environment.clean">
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <legend>Cleaniness</legend>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="flex-container" required>
                        <input type="radio" id="env_clean-5" name="rating__env_clean" value="5">
                        <label for="env_clean-5"><svg><title>Five Stars</title><use 
                         xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="env_clean-4" name="rating__env_clean" value="4">
                        <label for="env_clean-4"><svg><title>Four Stars</title><use 
                         xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="env_clean-3" name="rating__env_clean" value="3">
                        <label for="env_clean-3"><svg><title>Three Stars</title><use 
                         xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="env_clean-2" name="rating__env_clean" value="2">
                        <label for="env_clean-2"><svg><title>Two Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="env_clean-1" name="rating__env_clean" value="1">
                        <label for="env_clean-1"><svg><title>One Star</title><use xlink:href="#star"> 
                    </use></svg></label>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset> 



                <fieldset class="rating rating__experience" required>
                    <legend>How would you rate your overall experience?</legend>
                    <div class="flex-container">
                        <input type="radio" id="experience-5" name="rating__experience" value="5">
                        <label for="experience-5"><svg><title>Five Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="experience-4" name="rating__experience" value="4">
                        <label for="experience-4"><svg><title>Four Stars</title><use 
                         xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="experience-3" name="rating__experience" value="3">
                        <label for="experience-3"><svg><title>Three Stars</title><use 
                          xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="experience-2" name="rating__experience" value="2">
                        <label for="experience-2"><svg><title>Two Stars</title><use 
                        xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="experience-1" name="rating__experience" value="1">
                        <label for="experience-1"><svg><title>One Stars</title><use 
                    xlink:href="#star"></use></svg></label>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

            <a href="index.html">
            <button type="submit" feedbackSubmit()>Submit</button>
            </a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script  src="js/submit.js"></script> 
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i'm just trying to check if data is being sent to firebase so this is the code that i've used in javascript.

```
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  //firebase.analytics();


  const formMessage = firebase.database().ref().child('FeedbackObj');

document
  .getElementById('feedback_form')
  .addEventListener('submit', formSubmit);

//document.getElementById('appointmentForm').addEventListener('submit', formSubmit);

//Submit form
function feedbackSubmit()//e) 
{
  //e.preventDefault();
  // Get Values from the DOM
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

    sendMessage(date,time);
    console.log("Data saved successfully.");

    document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'block';

  //Hide Alert Message After Seven Seconds
  setTimeout(function() {document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'none';
  }, 7000);

  document.getElementById('feedback_form').reset();

}

function sendMessage(date,time) 
{
  let newFormMessage = formMessage.push();
  console.log("Data saved successfully.");
  newFormMessage.set({
    Dated: date,
    Time:time
  });
}
```

But even after deploying the website again and again it still doesn't send the data. And the submit button does not redirect back to "index.html". My database rules allow data to be written.

Comment: `newFormMessage.set()` returns a Promise. Try adding a try / catch block (or callbacks) to see if it is getting fulfilled.

Comment: It is giving an error in "firebase.database" claiming that it is not a function. I appreciate the help btw.

Comment: It started working. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors in your files.

1. You must add the firebase products you need to use between the `'<head>'` tags of your html.
   Code: `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-database.js"></script>`
2. You are looking for an element by `Id` that does not exist in the Html.
   You must add the id attribute to the `'form'` tag.
   Code: `<form id="feedback_form" class="feedback_form">`
3. You are having trouble with the `'pattern'` attribute of the `'Department'` field. It must not contain spaces inside the quotes. It must be so.
   Code: `pattern="[\w]{1,25}"`
4. You have errors within the html, when opening and closing tags, they do not match.
   You should pay more attention on that.
   Code: `<div> ... content ... </div>`
5. You must choose the way you will submit. Through an `'addEventListener'`, or through the `onclick="myFunction()"` attribute of html.
   You can see an example here: [Sample](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)
6. When you try to assign styles to the element `'.alert'`, you get an error, the search returns `null`.
   These errors prevent your code from going its way.

Finally, by following the steps in the Firebase Database documentation: [Firebase Database Read-and-Write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

The code would look

Firebase Database: [Image of what the data stored in the Firebase Database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy9ft.png)

HTML Code:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
  ...
</head>

<body>
  ...
  <form id="feedback_form" class="feedback_form">
    ...
    <!-- If you want to redirect to "index.html", you can do it in .js, after typing in Firebase. -->
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  ...
  <script src="js/submit.js"></script> 
</body>
```

JS Code:

```
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Get a reference to the database service
var database = firebase.database();

/* Add to Database */
function sendToDatabase(date,time) {
  database.ref('feedbackObj').set({
    date: date,
    time: time
  });
}

/* Submit Comment Function */
function submitComment(event) {
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

  sendToDatabase(date, time);

  form.reset();
  event.preventDefault();
}

const form = document.getElementById('feedback_form');
form.addEventListener('submit', submitComment);
```

Comment: Hi @MyraFaisal, Does this solution work for you? Anything, let me know.

Comment: I fixed all the errors you pointed out and even now when i run it it shows an error in "firebase.database()" and says it is not a function. Also thank you for the help!